# I need some clarification about conjunctions

Tags: conjunctions, clauses

1. He has a big appetite, for he is young.
2. He has a big appetite because he is young.

Due to the coordinating conjunction "for", the first sentence is the only one that has two independent clauses, right?

If I'm correct... where's the logic in that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"For" is a coordinating conjunction, while "because" is a subordinating conjunction.  This means that even though the two sentences mean the same thing, (1) consists of two independent clauses, while (2) consists of an independent clause plus a subordinate clause.

> (1)    He has a big appetite, **for** he is young.

> (2)    He has a big appetite **because** he is young.

At first sight, this is illogical.  But the main difference between coordinators and subordinators is that, with a subordinator, you can move the subordinate clause to the start of the sentence, and the sentence still makes sense and carries the same meaning: ***Because** he is young, he has a big appetite*.  You can't do this with a coordinator.